# subscribe keys of and observable in Angular/RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i dont find this awnser in the documentation (angular and rxjs), when I make a HttpCliente request in angular an return an observable, example:

```
let request = this.http.get(url);
request.subscribe(
  { 
    next: data => console.log(data),
    error: error => console.log(data)
  }
);
```

the doubt: only will 'fall' into the next if the request answer is 200? any other as 403, 400, 201, etc will 'fall' into error?

Comment: Not only 200. Any success/redirect codes, i.e. 2xx/3xx will hit `next`, any error codes 4xx/5xx will hit `error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2xx` codes are consider valid and will emit a `next` notification.

Any other code will throw an `Error`.

---

Following code is extracted from the `HttpXhrBackend` implementation. [Full code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts)

```
 ...
 
 // ok determines whether the response will be transmitted on the event or
 // error channel. Unsuccessful status codes (not 2xx) will always be errors,
 // but a successful status code can still result in an error if the user
 // asked for JSON data and the body cannot be parsed as such.
 let ok = status >= 200 && status < 300;
 
 ...
```

Cheers